# Although I can print the relevant part of the year, how do I get the information related to mobile? i'm using python

Tags: python, json

```
a={'year':2021,'contactnum': [{'mobile': '+94#######'}, {'lan': '+94#######'}]
```

print(a['year'])

Although I can print the relevant part of the year, how do I get the information related to mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Since `contactnum` is a list (`[]`), you'll have to index the first (zeroth) entry of it:

```
print(a["contactnum"][0]["mobile"])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you are missing a closing curly bracket at the end of your line of code to indicate the end of your dictionary.
After this, you can access the desired part with

```
print(a['contactnum'][0]['mobile'])
```